# My aunt's cat's behavior has changed

Tags: cats

Miss Kitty is 19 yrs young. She has started to bite my aunt (which is 89 yrs young ). Miss Kitty has also been drinking a lot of water and sleeping in her cat box .6 months ago my aunt listed her husband of 40+ yrs . But miss kitty just started the biting and sleeping in her box these last 2 weeks. As for her drinking all the time started 2-3 months ago maybe 4 months ago my aunt doesn't remember. Can you help my aunt's cat please .

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like kidney failure. Get the cat to the vet ***now***.